# Change color of a particular area in a shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, shader

I need to manipulate the color of a particular area in a shader. The area is hexagonal and determined by outside sources at runtime.

I used a hexagonal texture on the shader and I need to change the colors of some of the cells individually.

I'm using a shader from Unity3D Wiki but I dont have much experience with shaders.

If someone could  provide me a source that I can figure out how I would be glad.

Here is the shader I'm using and the link,

```
Shader "Custom/Shield"
{

Properties
{
    _Color("_Color", Color) = (0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0)
    _Inside("_Inside", Range(0.0,2.0) ) = 0.0
    _Rim("_Rim", Range(0.0,1.0) ) = 1.2
    _Texture("_Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Speed("_Speed", Range(0.5,5.0) ) = 0.5
    _Tile("_Tile", Range(1.0,10.0) ) = 5.0
    _Strength("_Strength", Range(0.0,5.0) ) = 1.5
}

SubShader
{
    Tags
    {
        "Queue"="Transparent"
        "IgnoreProjector"="True"
        "RenderType"="Transparent"

    }


Cull Back
ZWrite On
ZTest LEqual


CGPROGRAM
#pragma surface surf BlinnPhongEditor alpha vertex:vert
//#pragma target 3.0


fixed4 _Color;
sampler2D _CameraDepthTexture;
fixed _Inside;
fixed _Rim;
sampler2D _Texture;
fixed _Speed;
fixed _Tile;
fixed _Strength;

struct EditorSurfaceOutput
    {
        half3 Albedo;
        half3 Normal;
        half3 Emission;
        half3 Gloss;
        half Specular;
        half Alpha;
    };

inline half4 LightingBlinnPhongEditor_PrePass (EditorSurfaceOutput s, half4 light)
{
    half3 spec = light.a * s.Gloss;

    half4 c;

    c.rgb = (s.Albedo * light.rgb + light.rgb * spec);

    c.a = s.Alpha + Luminance(spec);

    return c;


}

inline half4 LightingBlinnPhongEditor (EditorSurfaceOutput s, half3 lightDir, half3 viewDir, half atten)
{
    viewDir = normalize(viewDir);
    half3 h = normalize (lightDir + viewDir);

    half diff = max (0, dot (s.Normal, lightDir));

    float nh = max (0, dot (s.Normal, h));
    float3 spec = pow (nh, s.Specular*128.0) * s.Gloss;

    half4 res;
    res.rgb = _LightColor0.rgb * (diff * atten * 2.0);
    res.w = spec * Luminance (_LightColor0.rgb);

    return LightingBlinnPhongEditor_PrePass( s, res );
}

struct Input
{
    float4 screenPos;
    float3 viewDir;
    float2 uv_Texture;
};


void vert (inout appdata_full v, out Input o)
{
    UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input,o);
}


void surf (Input IN, inout EditorSurfaceOutput o)
{
    o.Albedo = fixed3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    o.Normal = fixed3(0.0,0.0,1.0);
    o.Emission = 0.0;
    o.Gloss = 0.0;
    o.Specular = 0.0;
    o.Alpha = 1.0;
    float4 ScreenDepthDiff0= LinearEyeDepth (tex2Dproj(_CameraDepthTexture, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(IN.screenPos)).r) - IN.screenPos.z;
    float4 Saturate0=fixed4(0.3,0.3,0.3,1.0);//
    float4 Fresnel0_1_NoInput = fixed4(0,0,1,1);
    float dNorm = 1.0 - dot(normalize(float4(IN.viewDir, 1.0).xyz), normalize(Fresnel0_1_NoInput.xyz) );
    float4 Fresnel0 = float4(dNorm,dNorm,dNorm,dNorm);
    float4 Step0=step(Fresnel0,float4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ));
    float4 Clamp0=clamp(Step0,_Inside.xxxx,float4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ));
    float4 Pow0=pow(Fresnel0,(_Rim).xxxx);
    float4 Multiply5=_Time * _Speed.xxxx;
    float4 UV_Pan0=float4((IN.uv_Texture.xyxy).x,(IN.uv_Texture.xyxy).y + Multiply5.x,(IN.uv_Texture.xyxy).z,(IN.uv_Texture.xyxy).w);
    float4 Multiply1=UV_Pan0 * _Tile.xxxx;
    float4 Tex2D0=tex2D(_Texture,Multiply1.xy);
    float4 Multiply2=Tex2D0 * _Strength.xxxx;
    float4 Multiply0=Pow0 * Multiply2;
    float4 Multiply3=Clamp0 * Multiply0;
    float4 Multiply4=Saturate0 * Multiply3;
    o.Emission = Multiply3.xyz * _Color.rgb;
    o.Alpha =  Multiply3.w * _Color.a;

}
ENDCG
}
Fallback "Diffuse"
}
```

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Shield

Comment: Do you want to write a shader for unity3d or for OpenGL or for OpenGL-es?

Comment: I will use it in Unity , I know they are different things but either is fine , I can try to implement that for Unity once I get how they work.

Answer (score 0):

> Shader programs can actually have more parameters (like matrices, vectors and floats) that are set on the material from code at runtime, but if they are not part of the Properties block then their values will not be saved. This is mostly useful for values that are completely script code-driven (using Material.SetFloat and similar functions).

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Properties.html

It would seem that you would use have to use unique materials with different colors. You can then dynamically adjust the material color with Material.SetColor() .

Comment: I know how to handle the Unity part, I need to know how to manipulate the shader itself , changing color on certain areas of a single material.